# UITableViewCell with UITextField that is firstResponder not being called in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController displaying 50 items. It's a plain table view and it's using the value1 cell type. When I tap on a row I add a UITextField to that cell (it has a brilliant green background for debugging). At this point, I have not made it the first responder. Now, if I scroll the table view everything is normal. As one would expect, the cell with the bright green text field gets dequeued and reused and appears in other cells randomly.

Two interesting things happen when I make that text field the first responder.

1. I can scroll all day and that cell is never dequeued and reused.
2. tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: is never called for the cell that has the text field that is the first responder.

It's like the cell is pulled from the pool. And as soon as the text field is not the first responder things go back to normal.

Here's the relevant code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"indexPath= %@", indexPath);
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Label %@", self.items[indexPath.row]];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell addSubview:self.textFieldForEditing];
    //[self.textFieldForEditing becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

And it doesn't matter how I make the text field the first responder. Whether I uncomment the line in didSelectRowAtIndexPath: or tap on the text field. Either way, same behaviour.

From a certain point of view this behaviour is handy. It becomes unnecessary to implement dequeueing management code to prevent the text field from appearing where it shouldn't.

But I can't find this behaviour documented anywhere. Is this normal?

Comment: Yes, I think this is pretty normal. It has the keyboard focus and therefore has some sort of "strong" reference to it, which prevents it from being dequeued.